# Running java agents in lotus notes 9

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, javaagents

Hi I am new in using lotus notes 9 , i created a form  with some fields and  a save button  that is calling a java agent !  my problek is when i excute the form and click the button i get an error saying that the document is not saved. this is the agent code. thank you

```
import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.AgentContext;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.Session;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {



public void NotesMain() {
    try {
        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

        // (Your code goes here)

        Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
        Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();

        doc = db.createDocument();
        doc.save();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext(); will retrieve the in-memory document.
Your document isn´t saved yet; so you don´t have a doc in memory.

save your doc first an then run an agent with getDocumentContext.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the "Target" in the agent properties (Basics tab).  It's probably set to "All Selected Documents"  If it's not set to "None" you can get that same error message.